# Compress video with ffmpeg4android library

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression

I tried to follow [ffmpeg4android library](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html), and I get the problem when compressing the video, as the Log image below.

I use intent to transfer to Compressing Media class,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CompressingMedia.class);
intent.putExtra("file_path", mLlItems.get(0).getPath());
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the class was transfered to :

```
public class CompressingMedia extends BaseWizard {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "path " + intent.getExtras().getString("file_path"));
    // /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20140312_090612.mp4

    String command = "ffmpeg -y -i " + intent.getExtras().getString("file_path") + 
            " -strict experimental -s 320x240 -r 15 -aspect 3:4 -ab 12288 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -sample_fmt s16 /sdcard/out.mp4";

    // if you want to change the default work location (/sdcard/videokit/) use the uncomment the below method.
    // It must be defined before calling the copyLicenseAndDemoFilesFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded method,
    // in order for this method to copy the assets to the correct location.
            //      setWorkingFolder("/sdcard/videokit/");

    // this will copy the license file and the demo video file.
    // to the videokit work folder location.
    // without the license file the library will not work.
    copyLicenseAndDemoFilesFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded();

    commandStr = command;
    setCommand(commandStr);

    runTranscoing();
    }
}
```

Although I received the notification Transcoding Successfully, but it looks like the capacity of file after compressing is always be 0. (the log in the bottom of images)

I don't know the result as image below is good or not, I can not get the expected result - The video was compressed totally successfully.

Someone know why after compressing the file is always be 0, please tell me. Thanks.

This is the Log Cat :

> 03-13 14:49:45.655: I/ActivityManager(6065): Timeline:
>   Activity_launch_request id:app.cloudstringers time:38212359
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.665: V/Home(6065): Global ID is 000400010007;Sell is 3
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.770: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): path
>   /storage/emulated/0/videokit/out.mp4
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.770: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): workingFolderPath:
>   /sdcard/videokit/
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.775: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Working directory exists,
>   not coping assests (license file and demo videos)
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.785: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): output directory exists.
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.785: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): Command is set
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.785: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): set
>   remoteNotificationIconId: 0
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.785: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client Cannot unbind -
>   service not bound
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.785: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client stopService()
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.790: W/ContextImpl(6065): Implicit intents with
>   startService are not safe: Intent {
>   act=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:499
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.stopService:451
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.runTranscoing:285
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.795: I/ffmpeg4android(6065):
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!services.size(): 1
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.795: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): putting Base categoty
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.810: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): started: 
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.810: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client startService()
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.810: D/ffmpeg4android(6065):  bindService() called
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.815: W/ContextImpl(6065): Implicit intents with
>   startService are not safe: Intent {
>   act=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.bindService:462
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.runTranscoing:288
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.820: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client bindService()
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.935: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): =======service onCreate():
>   Stopping forground (to overcome 2.3.x bug)
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.935: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): =======service
>   onBind()=======
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.940: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): ===onStartCommand called
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.940: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): ===onStartCommand cat:
>   Base
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.940: D/ffmpeg4android(6616): onStartCommand,
>   START_STICKY, base Command
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.955: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): get
>   remoteNotificationIconId: 0
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.955: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): notifIcon is set
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.955: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): Start RemoteService with
>   notification id: 5326
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.965: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): Run called.
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.965: D/ffmpeg4android(6616): Sleeping, waiting for
>   command
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client
>   onServiceConnected()
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): invokeService called
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): licenseCheck in path:
>   /sdcard/videokit
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): isLicExistsComplex...
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): trying to open
>   /sdcard/videokit/ffmpeglicense.lic
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): license file found...
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): time decoded: 1394535283
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): timeStrDec 1394535283 is a valid
>   number.
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): time diff: 161702
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/Videokit(6065): You used 1 of your 15 trial
>   days.
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): setting remote
>   notification info
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: D/ffmpeg4android(6616): command items num: 21
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: D/ffmpeg4android(6616): command: ffmpeg -y -i 
>   /storage/emulated/0/videokit/out.mp4 -strict experimental -s 320x240
>   -r 15 -aspect 3:4 -ab 12288 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -sample_fmt s16 /sdcard/out.mp4
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: D/ffmpeg4android(6616): workingFolder from remote:
>   /sdcard/videokit
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.970: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): deleteing:
>   /sdcard/videokit/vk.log isdeleted: true
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.975: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): deleteing:
>   /sdcard/videokit/ffmpeg4android.log isdeleted: false
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.975: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): deleteing:
>   /sdcard/videokit/videokit.log isdeleted: true
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.980: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client invokeService()
>
> 03-13 14:49:45.980: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Acquire wake lock
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.265: D/ffmpeg4android(6616): Sleeping, waiting for
>   command
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.295: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): TranscodeBackground
>   doInBackground started
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.295: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): =======remote service
>   runTranscoding ======
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.340: V/HomeAsync(6065): TOTAL_SPACE is
>   1;AVAILABLE_SPACE is 0.451
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.345: I/ActivityManager(6065): Timeline: Activity_idle
>   id: android.os.BinderProxy@423deed8 time:38213045
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.345: I/ActivityManager(6065): Timeline: Activity_idle
>   id: android.os.BinderProxy@420323a0 time:38213045
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.565: D/dalvikvm(6616): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/app.cloudstringers-2/libvideokit.so 0x41b285f0
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.570: D/dalvikvm(6616): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/app.cloudstringers-2/libvideokit.so 0x41b285f0
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.570: I/Videokit(6616): Loading native library compiled
>   at 21:59:53 Oct 23 2013
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/ffmpeg4android(6616): ===============Running
>   command from thread path: /sdcard/videokit
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): vk ffmpeg sdcardPath:
>   /sdcard/videokit
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): licenseCheck in path:
>   /sdcard/videokit
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): isLicExistsComplex...
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): trying to open
>   /sdcard/videokit/ffmpeglicense.lic
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): license file found...
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/ffmpeg4android(6616):
>   =======ProgressBackgroundRemote doInBackground=========
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): time decoded: 1394535283
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): timeStrDec 1394535283 is a valid
>   number.
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): time diff: 161703
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: I/Videokit(6616): You used 1 of your 15 trial
>   days.
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: D/Videokit(6616): license check rc: 0
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: D/Videokit(6616): run() called verion 2.0
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.575: D/Videokit(6616): run passing off to main()
>
> 03-13 14:49:46.800: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): onServiceDisconnected
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.640: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): Got real duration:
>   00:00:07.78
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.640: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): ==== getting
>   currentVkLogSize from VK
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.640: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): currentVkLogSize: 5751
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.645: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): No ffmpeg4android_log
>   file, using vk log
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.645: I/line(6065): _rate, rate, width or height
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: I/line(6065): Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: I/line(6065): Statistics: 72873 bytes read, 2
>   seeks
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): currentTimeStr: exit
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): ============Found one of
>   the exit tokens in the log============
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): onProgressUpdate: 100
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Releasing wake lock
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.650: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): TranscodeBackground
>   onPostExecute
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.700: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): /sdcard/videokit/null
>   length in bytes: 0
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.700: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): showNotifications
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.700: W/ffmpeg4android(6065): output file is not set use
>   the setOutputFilePath method to set the full output file path
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.705: I/ffmpeg4android(6065): FFMPEG finished.
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.710: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): releaseService()
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.710: D/ffmpeg4android(6065): Client stopService()
>
> 03-13 14:49:48.710: W/ContextImpl(6065): Implicit intents with
>   startService are not safe: Intent {
>   act=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.FFMpegRemoteServiceBridge }
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.stopService:499
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.stopService:451
>   com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android_client.BaseWizard.handleServiceFinished:513

Comment: Could you please post the code and output as text, not as images?

Comment: Thanks, I already changed the coding to the text. The log is so long. I think it not really be easy to copy/paste them into this question, right?

Comment: The image you attached is not only unreadable without clicking on it, but also makes it impossible to search anything there - which is what the logs typically are for. Also looking on your code, if your path has any spaces or shell symbols in it, it won't work (and you may get a nice security hole there too)

Comment: Ahhh, really thanks for your advice George Y. Already edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also consider using the real (and free!) FFmpeg for Android from the original source: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android instead of using some third-party compilation from a guy who seems to violate FFmpeg LGPL license.

Comment: Hello, I tried with real ffmpeg. But it looks like difficult to integrate with it. Would you like to tell me how? I can call C function in C file. I can build ffmpeg so file also. Thanks

Comment: Please note that you're answering the question which is more than a  year old . At that time there was no source code available of the FFmpeg4Android, nor other FFMpeg requirements were fulfilled, so that project indeed WAS violating the LGPL when the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, the command you used is not correct. Its possible your video file does not correspond to the size, and aspect parameters you used.

See your log line here:
03-13 14:49:48.645: I/line(6065): _rate, rate, width or height

The best way is to post a link to the input video file so I can check it.

Comment: hello, I no longer use this library, it not really good to use, I need use ffmpeg library manually. It should be better than this one, thank you.